# Searching for a function with one parameter like in the example

Tags: functional-analysis

I am searching for a math function with one paramter **a** which is doing the weighting like in the picture. For a=0 the function is linear (y=x) and for the maximum a=1 the weighting is high for P_2 and low for P_1 (inverse for the minimum a=-1). Which function is it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0zL.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For a simple starting point, let's take $P_1 = (0,0)$ and $P_2=(1,1)$. Would a function like
$$
f(x) = x^{\left(2^{\alpha} \right)}
$$
satisfy your needs? In other words, does it look good to you? You can also change the 2 to 3 or 4. Here's the graph, where you can play with the value of $\alpha$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nfzbv7jz1g